# How can i redirect to an specific url when came back from success printing (no cancel) in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, redirect, printing, mozilla

I have a page that has some data for printing. i want to redirect this page to a specific url in **firefox** when print successfully done. 
now i can redirect in chrome without any problem but in firefox page just  redirect if print cancel by user.
is there any solution for this problem?

```
function print() {
    window.print();
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:8000/admin/orders";
    console.log('hi');
}
```

this is my function, `window.location.href` do not run but `console.log` run successfully!

Comment: Show your code that's not working as intended.

Comment: i added my code to the question.